# installing after windows 7

Tags: windows, files, backup, startup, transfer

I currently have windows 7 installed on my laptop which is very capable of supporting ubuntu and windows 7 with respect to hardware. Im actually having startup issues in windows 7 atm, that being the main reason for my looking into ubuntu. Since i cannot boot windows 7 at this time, i want to "try" ubuntu on my system with windows 7 present, and am wondering if while i do this, I'll be able to see my windows files while running the ubuntu OS. I ultimately want to back up my files onto an external hard drive in ubuntu, and then go ahead with a full install of ubuntu on my system. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can solve startup issues using a Windows 7 DVD and selecting the proper option.
2. Yes you can see (read: mount) your Windows partition and check your
   files, and then make a back up. Boot the Ubuntu live CD get to the **Try Ubuntu** screen and then open the file manager (Nautilus) in it look out for the Windows partition click and it will mount it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you install Ubuntu you still can access your Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Ubuntu Live Cd/Usb** to try it and also to **backup** your files .

If you are considering to install it in **Dual Boot** configuration , refer this Graphical explanation here.

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

and here too

[Ubuntu / Windows Dual Boot](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p22.html).

**Dual-Boot** is recommended more than Wubi.